# Python coding problems (Utf-8, Hungarian language)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-2.x

I wrote a script in Python 2 which is separated in 4-5 modules. I use the Hungarian language in the script, which contains several unusual characters like öüóőúéáűí. I wrote the modules on Win7 with an original cp-1250 coding, and then I moved to Ubuntu raring, where the system default is Utf-8.

First Tkinter left the spec. letter containing labels blank, which I managed to debug by setting every coding in the beginning of the modules to `# -*- Utf-8 -*-`.

Entries started to go mad too. Their `.get()` methods raised UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...

And finally if for example module `a.py` had a dictionary `dict = {'Sándor': 16}` and module `b.py` has a line `a.dict['Sándor']`, it raises KeyError, as if dict didn't contain `'Sándor'`. It doesn't do this with strings containing only normal characters, not does this with dictionaries of the module's own.

Answer (score 3):

> I wrote a script in python2... I use the Hungarian language in the script...

Did you use `unicode` literals? No, you did not. Rewrite your script to use and handle them properly.

```
{u'Sándor': 16}
```

[Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)